# Ito Isometry for conditional expectations

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

Is Ito's isometry true for conditional expectations too?

I mean, is it true that:$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\int_0^tX_sdB_s\right)^2\ |\ \mathcal{F}_t^B\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^tX^2_sds\ |\ \mathcal{F}_t^B\right]$$
where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion and $\mathcal{F}_t^B$ the natural filtration?

Answer (score 11):

This equality cannot hold true as the following counterexample shows:

For fixed $t>0$ set $X_s(\omega) := 1_{[0,t]}(s)$. Then the left-hand side is equal to

$$\mathbb{E} \bigg( \underbrace{\left(\int_0^t X_s \, dB_s \right)^2}_{B_t^2} \mid \mathcal{F}_t^B \bigg) = \mathbb{E}(B_t^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_t^B)=B_t^2$$

whereas the right-hand side equals

$$\mathbb{E} \left(\int_0^t X_s^2 \, ds  \mid \mathcal{F}_t^B \right) = \mathbb{E}(t \mid \mathcal{F}_t^B)=t$$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it was just a typo in your question :) The following version of Ito's isometry holds true
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\int_a^b X_s\,dB_s\right|^2\mid\mathcal{F}^B_a\right] = \mathbb{E}[\int_a^b X_s^2\,ds\mid\mathcal{F}^B_a]=\int_a^b\mathbb{E}[X_s^2\mid\mathcal{F}^B_a]\,ds.
$$
To see that prove that for every real-valued bounded $\mathcal{F}^B_a$-measurable random variable $h$ holds
$$
\int_a^bhX_s\,dB_s = h\int_a^b X_s\,dB_s
$$
and use Tonelli's theorem.