# Find the compenstor of the standard ito integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation, martingales, stochastic-integrals

Let $B_t$ be a Brownian motion and let $\{\mathcal F_t : a<t<b\}$ be a filtration such that for each $t$ we have that $B_t$ is $\mathcal F_t$ measurable and for and $s<t$, the random variable $B_t-B_s$ is independent of the sigma field $\mathcal F_s$. Lastly let $L_{ad}^2[(a,b)\times \Omega]$ be this set of stocastic processes $f(t,\omega)$ such that $\int_a^bEf(s)^2 \, ds < \infty$ and $f(t,\omega)$ is adapted to the filtration $\mathcal F_t$

> Consider $M_t$ = $\int_a^bf(s) \, dB(s)$. Then it is known that $M_t$ is a martingale and also $M_t^2$ is a submartingale. The Doob-submartingale decomposition says that there exists an increasing and right continuous random variable $\langle M \rangle_t$ such that $M_t^2- \langle M \rangle_t$ is a martingale. Find $\langle M \rangle_t$

I am told that $\langle M \rangle_t=\int_a^bf(s)^2ds$. Here is what I have done in order to show this.

Let $k<t$.

\begin{align*}& E\left[\left(\int_a^tf(s)\,dB(s)\right)^2 - \int_a^tf(s)^2 \, ds\mid\mathcal F_k\right] \\ &= E\left[\left(\int_a^kf(s)dB(s)+\int_k^tf(s)\,dB(s)\right)^2 - \int_a^tf(s)^2 \, ds\mid\mathcal F_k\right]
\\ &= E\left[\left(\int_a^kf(s)\,dB(s)\right)^2+\left(\int_k^tf(s)\,dB(s)\right)^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_k \right] \\ &\quad +2 E\left[ \int_a^kf(s)\,dB(s)\int_k^tf(s)\,dB(s) - \int_a^tf(s)^2\,ds\mid\mathcal F_k\right]
\\ &= \left(\int_a^kf(s)\,dB(s)\right)^2 - \int_a^kf(s)^2 \, ds \\ &\quad +E\left[\left(\int_k^tf(s)\,dB(s)\right)^2+2\int_a^kf(s)\,dB(s)\int_k^tf(s)\,dB(s) - \int_k^tf(s)^2 \, ds\mid\mathcal F_k\right] \end{align*}

where the last equality follows from the definition of our filtration. Now I'll focus on the remaining conditional expectation term. For the following I will use the independence of the increments of the Brownian motions and the fact that $E\left[\left(\int_a^bg(s) \, dB(s)\right)^2\right]=\int_a^bE(g(s)^2) \, ds$ and $E\left[\int_a^bg(s) \, dB(s)\right]=0$ I get

\begin{align*} &E\left[\left(\int_k^tf(s) \, dB(s)\right)^2+2\int_a^kf(s) \, dB(s)\int_k^tf(s) \, dB(s) - \int_k^tf(s)^2 \, ds\mid\mathcal F_k\right]  \\ &= \int_k^tE(f(s)^2) \, ds +0-\int_k^tE(f(s)^2\mid\mathcal F_k) \, ds \end{align*}

Now putting everything together we see that

\begin{align*} &E\left[\left(\int_a^tf(s) \, dB(s)\right)^2 - \int_a^tf(s)^2 \, ds\mid\mathcal F_k\right] \\ &=\left(\int_a^kf(s) \, dB(s)\right)^2 - \int_a^kf(s)^2 \, ds + \int_k^tE(f(s)^2) \, ds -\int_k^tE(f(s)^2\mid\mathcal F_k) \, ds. \end{align*}

If the last two terms cancelled each other out, i.e. $$\int_k^tE(f(s)^2) \, ds =\int_k^tE(f(s)^2\mid\mathcal F_k) \, ds$$ then we would be done and we would then see that $$\int_a^tE(f(s)^2) \, ds -\int_a^tE(f(s)^2\mid\mathcal F_k) \, ds$$ is a martingale. But im not sure that these terms do cancel each other out. So did I make a mistake somewhere above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with the remaining conditional expectation term, you forgot to take the conditional expectation of one ingredients, namely of

$$\left( \int_k^t f(s) \, dB_s \right)^2.$$

In your calculation you seem to use that

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \left[ \int_k^t f(s) \, dB_s \right]^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_k \right) =  \mathbb{E} \left( \int_k^t f(s)^2 \, ds \right)$$ but this fails to hold true; it should read 
$$\mathbb{E} \left( \left[ \int_k^t f(s) \, dB_s \right]^2 \mid \mathcal{F}_k \right) =  \mathbb{E} \left( \int_k^t f(s)^2 \, ds \mid \color{red}{\mathcal{F}_k} \right)$$

instead, see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2559932/36150) for a proof. Fixing this mistake will immediately solve your problem.

Comment: My mistake was that I incorrectly assumed that $\left( \int_k^t f(s) \, dB_s\right)^2  $ was independent of $\mathcal F_k$. I just read through the question you referenced and saw what you did there. Using those same techniques is it true that we can then further prove that $$ E\left(\int_k^tf(s)dB(s)\int_k^tg(s)dB(s) \; \vert \; \mathcal F_k\right) = E\left(\int_k^tf(s)g(s)ds \; \vert \; \mathcal F_k\right) $$.

Comment: @alpastor Yes, that's an immediate consequence... just use the polarization identity $$xy = \frac{1}{4}((x+y)^2-(x-y)^2)$$ for $$x \hat{=} \int_k^t f(s) \, dB_s \qquad y \hat{=} \int_k^t g(s) \, dB_s$$

Comment: Cool thank you, you're always very helpful!

Comment: @alpastor Glad I could help you; you are welcome.

Comment: I have one more question about this. Why isnt $\left( \int_k^t f(s) \, dB_s\right)^2$ independent of $\mathcal F_k$? Are there situations where this could be true? Would it be true if we could represent  $\left( \int_k^t f(s) \, dB_s\right) =\lim\limits_{\Vert \Delta_n \Vert \to 0} \sum_{i=1}^nf(t_{i-1})(B(t_i)-B(t_{i-1})$, where this limit means $L^2$ convergence. Also can we say $\left( \int_s^kf(s) \, dB_s\right)$ is independent of $\left( \int_k^t f(s) \, dB_s\right)$ for $s<k<t$?

Comment: @alpastor It all hinges on $f$. If $f(s)$ is for $s>k$ independent of $\mathcal{F}_k$, then the stochastic integral $\int_k^t f(s) \, dB_s$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_k$, note that this is, in particular, the case if $f$ is deterministic. If $f(s)$, $s>k$, is not independent of $\mathcal{F}_k$, then the stochastic integrals fails in general to be independent of $\mathcal{F}_k$ ... just consider for instance $f(s) := B(s)$.