# Expectation involving Brownian motion and stochastic integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let B be a standard brownian motion.

NOTE: in the exercise is suggeste to use that if X is$ N(o,\sigma^2)$ then$ E[X^4]=3\sigma^4$, so i would like to use this result.

I would like to compute $$E\bigg[B_s^2\big(\int_s^tB_udB_u\big)^2\bigg]$$

I started in the following way:
$$E\bigg[B_s^2\big(\int_s^tB_udB_u\big)^2\bigg]=E\Bigg[B_s^2E\bigg[\big(\int_s^tB_udB_u\big)^2\bigg|\mathcal F_s\bigg]\Bigg]=\frac14E\Bigg[B_s^2E\bigg[\big(B_t^2-t-(B_s^2-s) \ \big)^2\bigg|\mathcal F_s\bigg]\Bigg]=\frac14E\Bigg[B_s^2E\bigg[(B_t^2-t)^2-(B_s^2-s)^2\bigg|\mathcal F_s\bigg]\Bigg]$$

since by Ito $$\int_0^tB_udB_u- \int_0^sB_udB_u=\frac12[B_t^2-t-(B_s^2-s)]$$ and the last equality follows by property of the square integrable martingale

how could i proceed then?

Comment: Ito Isometry in the second step?

Comment: @UBM there is conditional expectation

Comment: \begin{align*}
E\bigg[B_s^2\big(\int_s^tB_udB_u\big)^2\bigg] &=E\Bigg[B_s^2E\bigg[\big(\int_s^tB_udB_u\big)^2\bigg|\mathcal F_s\Bigg] \Bigg] \\
&=E\Bigg[B_s^2E\bigg[ \int_s^tB^2_udu \bigg|\mathcal F_s\Bigg] \Bigg] \\
 &=...
\end{align*}

Comment: at least i never saw it, if you provide me a reference then is okey

Comment: @UBM https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263239/ito-isometry-for-conditional-expectations

Comment: That link is a different case. Note that in your case, the integral starts at time 's' and your $\sigma$-algebra is $\mathscr{F}_s.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed as follows,

$$I=E\bigg[B_s^2\big(\int_s^tB_udB_u\big)^2\bigg]=E\Bigg[B_s^2E_s\bigg[\big(\int_s^tB_udB_u\big)^2\bigg]\Bigg]=E\Bigg[B_s^2E_s\bigg[\int_s^tB_u^2du\bigg]\Bigg]$$

Use Ito's rule

$$d(B_u^2)=2B_udB_u + du,\implies B_u^2=B_s^2+2\int_s^uB_\tau dB_\tau+(u-s)$$

Then,

$$E_s\bigg[\int_s^tB_u^2du\bigg]=\int_s^tB_s^2du+\int_s^t(u-s)du=B_s^2(t-s)+\frac12(t-s)^2$$

Thus,
$$I=E\Bigg[B_s^2[B_s^2(t-s)+\frac12(t-s)^2]\Bigg]=3s^2(t-s)+\frac12s(t-s)^2$$
where $E[B_s^4] = 3s^2$ and $E[B_s^2] =s$ are used.

Comment: i think is wrong, you are missing a conditional expectation

Comment: @Buddy_ Sorry about that. Now it should be okay.

Comment: still missing conditional expectation

Comment: @Buddy_ Note that the shorthand $E_s[.]$ is used instead of $E[.|F_s]$ for conditional expectation.

Comment: looks strange that when you use ito formula you start from s and not from 0

Comment: @Buddy_ Note $\int_s^u d(B_\tau^2)=B_u^2 -  B_s^2$

Comment: @Buddy_ You want to start at $s$, because of the conditional expectation $E_s[.]$ to be taken

Comment: $\int_s^uB_\tau dB_\tau$ where it ends up this term?

Comment: @Buddy_ it vanishes upon expectation; it is a margingale

Comment: okey, and why this $\frac12$ ? $E_s\bigg[\int_s^tB_u^2du\bigg]=\int_s^tB_s^2du+\frac12\int_s^t(u-s)... $ also the last result of this row it seems to me wrong

Comment: @Buddy_ 1/2 is a typo. thanks for spotting it. removed.

Comment: $E_s\bigg[\int_s^tB_u^2du\bigg]=\int_s^tB_s^2du+\int_s^t(u-s)du=B_s^2(t-s)+\frac12(t-s)^2$... $+\frac12(t-s)^2$ is right?